# Unir dos listas en Python (Flask)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Primero expondré lo que intento hacer, estoy utilizando **Flask** para una Web, entonces, en una pagina muestro información que está alojada en una **lista** ya anteriormente declarada:

```
{% for i in productos%}
<li class="productos">
    <div>{{i}}<a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">print</i></a></div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Todo bien hasta ahí pero lo que pretendo es que en cada **href** se imprima el **id** de cada registro, estuve intentando con **listas bidimensionales** pero no lo logré, entonces, por ahí noté algo interesante, y se hace cuando se utilizan los mensajes **Flash**, y es esto:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=True) %}
{% for category, message in messages %}
<p id="mensaje" class="{{category}}">{{message}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Es como si en la lista **messages** (aunque no se si es una lista) hubieran **dos listas**, la de **category** y **message**, entonces no se si esa técnica sea propia de los mensajes flash o también se puede utilizar, en todo caso, usando esta idea, expondré lo que se me ocurrió que se podría hacer:

```
{% for producto,id in productos%}
<li class="productos">
    <div>{{producto}}<a href="delete?id={{id}}"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a><a href="imprimir?id={{id}}"><i class="material-icons">print</i></a></div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

No se si sea posible pero es por lo menos para que me entiendan la idea y quizás intuyan porque las **listas bidimensionales** no me funcionaron o quizás no se utilizarlas. No coloco parte del código Python porque no lo veo necesario, lo único importante sería como declarar las lista. Estoy usando python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que te funcione el ejemplo que pones, los elementos de la lista `productos` deben ser sub-listas (o tuplas) con dos elementos. La sintaxis que estás usando no es específica de Flask (o hablando más propiamente, de jinja, que es el lenguaje de *templates* usado por Flask), sino que en este caso es sintaxis Python, pues en Python también puedes hacer:

```py
for a, b in lista:
    print(a, b)
```

que sería equivalente a:

```py
for elemento in lista:
    a, b = elemento
    print(a, b)
```

la "magia" ocurre en la asignación `a, b = elemento`, que es un *desempaquetado de tuplas*. Lo que ve python en esa asignación es que al lado izquierdo hay dos variables, por lo que espera que al lado derecho haya una lista (o tupla) con dos elementos. Asignará el primero de esos elementos a la primera variable, y el segundo de ellos a la segunda (incidentalmente, es por esto que se puede hacer en python `x,y = y,x` para intercambiar dos variables en una sola sentencia).

En definitiva, tu estructura de datos `productos` podría ser algo como:

```py
productos = [ ("Teclado", "i213882") , ("Ratón", "t231232"), ("Monitor", "x77483") ]
```

Hay muchas más posibilidades, como por ejemplo que cada producto sea un objeto con un campo `nombre` y otro `id`, en cuyo caso desde Jinja podrías hacer:

```
{% for producto in productos%}
<li class="productos">
    <div>{{producto.name}}<a href="delete?id={{producto.id}}"><i class="material-icons">remove_red_eye</i></a><a href="imprimir?id={producto.id}}"><i class="material-icons">print</i></a></div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Este enfoque es el más habitual, sobre todo si estás usando un ORM que convierta a objetos las entidades de tu base de datos.

Comment: El segundo método funciona de 10, otra consulta, ¿Cómo seleccionaría los 5 últimos registros de la tabla productos? Tengo una columna de fecha de registro con la que se podría ordenar de manera ascendente, pero no estoy claro como usar order by en sqlalchemy, específicamente postgresql, he buscado pero no encuentro una solución que se adapte a mi problema.

Comment: Depende de tu modelo de datos, pero más o menos sería algo como `query = products.select().order_by(products.fecha_registro.desc()).limit(5)`

Comment: Gracias, con eso he logrado formular una consulta acorde a mi código, se puede dar el tema por resuelto.